# If X~N(-5, 10). I need to solve P(-6 < X < x) = 0.5.

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble solving the above given problem.

That is, if X~N(-5,10), then I need to determine what x is such that P(-6 < X < x) = 0.5

Here is what I tried to do.

P(Z < x + 5 / 10) - P(Z < -6+5/10) = 0.5

P(Z < x+5/10) - P(Z < -0.01) = 0.5

P(Z < x+5/10) - 0.4602 = 0.5

P(Z < x+5/10) = 0.5 + 0.4602

P(Z < x+5/10) = 0.9602

when x+5/10 = 1.75, so x = 0.5 (but this answer is incorrect).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the random variable. If $X:N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ which is normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is standard normal distribution. Thus, you need to divide by $\sqrt{10}$, not $10$.